# Texcount errors with bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle, texcount

I am trying to run texcount on a large tex file. It works fine when the bibliography is excluded from the count, but with `-incbib` it gives the following error message:

```
ERROR: Encountered } without corresponding {.
ERROR: Encountered \end without corresponding \begin
ERROR: Reached end of file while waiting for }.
ERROR: Reached end of file while waiting for \end.
ERROR: Environment ended while waiting for d{thebibliography}.
```

I'm using natbib with the "numbers" option and the style "unsrtnat" if its relevant. I've reviewed the bib and bbl files and there's nothing that appears to be wrong.

Comment: It is hard to tell precisely what goes wrong without more details. However, my suspicion is that the bbl file has a format that TeXcount cannot handle. You can try to run texcount on the bbl file separately, and then use the verbose output, `-v`, to see exactly where the error messages occur.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Apparently the problem is due to `\providecommand` in the `.bbl` file. I solved by replacing with `\newcommand` before running texcount.